# Why is web3.eth.subscribe not a function?

Tags: web3js

From the [web3 documentation](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html) I use this code sample:

```
var subscription = web3.eth.subscribe('logs', {
    address: '0x123456..',
    topics: ['0x12345...'] }, function(error, result){
    if (!error)
        console.log(log);
});
```

and I got this error:

```
TypeError: web3.eth.subscribe is not a function
```

is "subscribe" deprecated ? Is there a replacement for it ?

Comment: also read this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/48174309/573034

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation you are referring to says -

> This documentation is work in progress and web3.js 1.0 is not yet
>   released! You can find the current documentation for web3 0.x.x at
>   github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API.

That is the reason you are getting this error, you can follow [this](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API) 
 link for web3 js latest documentation.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

also address must be a contract address and not an account https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/1752#issuecomment-404385542